# Why sometimes some images is not loading using drawImage() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, image-loading

I am displaying some images on Canvas using `drawImage()` function. But when I refresh browser again and again, at times some images are not displayed. It seems that some images do not load properly. How to solve this issue?
JavaScript Code is-

```
var imageobj = new Array();
for (var d=0;d<calloutImageArray.length;d++)
{
     imageobj[d] = new Image();
     (function(d)
     {
       imageobj[d].src = sitePath+"ATOM/chapter1/book/"+calloutImageArray[d];
      imageobj[d].onload = function()
       {
            ctx.drawImage(imageobj[d], calloutImageArrayX[d], calloutImageArrayY[d],calloutImageArrayW[d], calloutImageArrayH[d]);        // getting value in array with X, Y coordinates & width, height
       }; 
     })(d);
}
```

I am getting all the values in all arrays.

Comment: And if I alert text after page load then its fine. But I don't want keep alert text.

Comment: Did you try calling the method on onDocumentReady()?

Comment: Above is loading in a function and this function is load by default. Means imagesfun(); function imagesfun(){  //my code }

Comment: its raising same issue in little time. its not solve fully

Comment: It's sounds like the onload event fires before you attached the callback to it (with cached images e.g) You should try setting the src after you attached the event handler